# Json in PHP from URL

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to display some elements from some json data at the following URL using the following code, but it isn't displaying anything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 

$url="http://fbclaurel.onthecity.org/plaza/events?format=json";

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data);

foreach($json->"global_event" as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
       echo $key . ': ' . $val;
       echo '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what do you get if you do `var_dump($json)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have a syntax error that is probably hidden due to your configured error reporting / display settings. It would be something like this

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"global_event"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

When developing, I recommend you **always** have the following properties in `php.ini`

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

#### Update

I've just checked the data from that API and it returns an array. Each array entry is an object with a single `global_event` property that is itself, another object. I imagine you're going to need something like this to iterate...

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
// the second "true" argument forces an array format result.
// I find it more appropriate when iterate keys or when keys
// might be invalid property names.

foreach ($json as $obj) {
    $globalEvent = $obj['global_event'];

    // now $globalEvent is an array with keys such as
    // addresses, body, created_at, ending_at, etc.
    // Note that few of these properties are simple, scalar values (like strings),
    // most are arrays themselves

    // display example...
    echo 'title: ', htmlspecialchars($globalEvent['title']), '<br>',
         'short_url: ', htmlspecialchars($globalEvent['short_url']), '<br>';
}
```

Comment: For reference, `$json->{"global_event"}` would work too

Comment: @scrowler True, but pointless. You only need to do that for property names that aren't traditionally supported by PHP.

Comment: @Phil He's talking about how you suggest using an array format rather than stdClass.  I also suggest leaving it in an object rather than using an associative array, and in which case you would use the syntax suggested by scrowler.

Comment: @Brad `global_event` is a valid property name. In fact, all of the JSON keys returned by the API are valid property names. There's no need to use the `{"key"}` format here. When I said *"pointless"*, I meant specifically in this case. I also don't really see any compelling reasons to choose *object* over *array* format in this (or any) case. It's personal preference really. When iterating keys, I prefer to know that the object in question is an array

Comment: @Phil Oh, you were talking about the bracket notation rather than the regular object property.  I see now.  Regarding array vs. object, I prefer to keep the data in its original form whenever possible.  That way, things like `is_array()` and `is_object()` work properly.

Comment: @Brad The data's original form is a string up until the point that you transform it via `json_decode`. It is neither an array nor an object and both PHP arrays and objects support the transformation. But, like I said, personal preference :)

Comment: One follow up question. How do I only display certain parts of the returned info (such as the value info from the "title" key or "short_url" key)?

Comment: @Phil Thanks Phil. I'm talking about the form it was in before it became JSON for transport.

Comment: @Brad I meant no such slight. Before it became a JSON string, it could have been anything; a PHP array or object encoded via `json_encode`, a C# `Dictionary`, a perl hash, JavaScript object literal, anything.

Comment: @Phil I see what you are getting at and I generally agree, but since we already lose some of those more specific types with the conversion to JSON, I prefer to keep things as pure as possible and keep objects as objects, and arrays as arrays.  If someone used something like an associative array in PHP which has to be an object in JSON, then so be it, but there is no way to know and the utility of keeping it as an object makes sense to me.

Comment: @chuckscoggins I've provided an example for you

Comment: @Brad The distinction between object and array is lost when it comes to PHP arrays though because they are not simply arrays but magical dynamic hash buckets that maintain order.

Answer (score 0):

do it like below

```
$url="http://fbclaurel.onthecity.org/plaza/events?format=json";

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data);

//echo '<pre>';
//print_r( $json[0]->global_event);

array_walk_recursive($json[0]->global_event, function ($a,$b){

echo 'KEY :'.$b.' & Value :'.$a.'<br>'; 

});
```

***OUTPUT***

```
KEY :starting_at & Value :2014-06-01T08:00:00-04:00
KEY :external_form_id & Value :
KEY :short_url & Value :http://bit.ly/1jOTqao
KEY :body & Value : Hymns are led by piano and organ. The choral music is sung by the Chapel Choir and the sermon message is given by Pastor Stan.  
KEY :ending_at & Value :2014-06-01T09:00:00-04:00
KEY :euid & Value :9ea33765449eb1476530c84d44a01cf200709cf9
KEY :title & Value :Classic Worship Service
KEY :updated_at & Value :2014-05-25T22:28:24-04:00
KEY :created_at & Value :2014-05-25T22:28:23-04:00
```

Comment: Downvoter MUST MUST mention the reason of downvote in comment...I think, this should be included in SO architecture.